# Dockerfile-dev vs Dockerdev-prod

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

This is my Docker project structure:

```
├── docker-compose-dev.yml
├── docker-compose-prod.yml
└── services
    ├── client
    │   ├── Dockerfile-dev
    │   ├── Dockerfile-prod
    ├── nginx
    │   ├── Dockerfile-dev
    │   ├── Dockerfile-prod
    │   ├── dev.conf
    │   └── prod.conf
    └── web
        ├── Dockerfile-dev   <----- THIS
        ├── Dockerfile-prod  <----- THIS
        ├── entrypoint-prod.sh
        ├── entrypoint.sh
        ├── htmlcov
        ├── manage.py
        ├── project
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── api
        │   │   ├── __init__.py
        │   │   ├── models.py
        │   │   ├── templates
        │   │   │   └── index.html
        │   │   └── users.py
        │   ├── config.py
        │   ├── db
        │   │   ├── Dockerfile
        │   │   └── create.sql
        └── requirements.txt
```

At development stage, `docker images` for my project have been ***successfully*** created with:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up --build
```

**Dockerfile-dev** on "web" service

```
# base image
FROM python:3.6-alpine

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add libffi-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && \
    apk add netcat-openbsd && \
    apk add bind-tools && \
    apk add --update --no-cache g++ libxslt-dev && \
    apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev

ENV PACKAGES="\
    dumb-init \
    musl \
    libc6-compat \
    linux-headers \
    build-base \
    bash \
    git \
    ca-certificates \
    freetype \
    libgfortran \
    libgcc \
    libstdc++ \
    openblas \
    tcl \
    tk \
    libssl1.0 \
    "
ENV PYTHON_PACKAGES="\
    numpy \
    matplotlib \
    scipy \
    scikit-learn \
    nltk \
    "   
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies python3 \
    && apk add --virtual build-runtime \
    build-base python3-dev openblas-dev freetype-dev pkgconfig gfortran \
    && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
    && python3 -m ensurepip \
    && rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools \
    && ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python \
    && ln -sf pip3 /usr/bin/pip \
    && rm -r /root/.cache \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir $PYTHON_PACKAGES \
    && pip3 install 'pandas<0.21.0' \
    && apk del build-runtime \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies $PACKAGES \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`docker ps -as` shows me the project up and running at `localhost`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES               SIZE
f88c27e5334f        dev3_nginx          "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   14 hours ago        Up 14 hours               0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       dev3_nginx_1        2B (virtual 16.1MB)
f77eb7949fef        dev3_client         "npm start"              14 hours ago        Up 14 hours               0.0.0.0:3007->3000/tcp   dev3_client_1       55B (virtual 553MB)
33b1b50931a6        dev3_web            "/usr/src/app/entryp…"   14 hours ago        Up 14 hours               0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp   dev3_web_1          35.3kB (virtual 3.32GB)
0e28363ab85a        dev3_web-db         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago          Up 14 hours               0.0.0.0:5435->5432/tcp   dev3_web-db_1       63B (virtual 71.7MB)
```

But I can't build my production images with:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up --build
```

**Dockerfile-prod** on "web" service

```
(...the same as Dockerfile-dev from top to here)

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# new
# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint-prod.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint-prod.sh

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# new
# run server
CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint-prod.sh"]
```

at production build hangs after `numpy` was installed, and it never resolves.

```
(...)
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (40.8.0)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.2
    Uninstalling pip-19.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.0.2
Successfully installed pip-19.0.3
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/26/07472b0de91851b6656cbc86e2f0d5d3a3128e7580f23295ef58b6862d6c/numpy-1.16.1.zip (5.1MB)
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/0c/653aec68e9cfb775c4fbae8f71011206e5e7fe4d60fcf01ea1a9d3bc957f/matplotlib-3.0.2.tar.gz (36.5MB)
# HANGS HERE ˆˆˆˆˆ
```

The problem does not seem to be `matplotlib` because if I remove this package it hangs at `scipy`, the next after `numpy`, and so on...

NOTE: I am trying to build production not at `localhost` but rather in a `docker-machine`.

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME              ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
testdriven-dev    -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.09.1   
testdriven-prod   *        amazonec2    Running   tcp://18.234.200.115:2376           v18.09.1 <------ THIS ONE
```

with:

```
$ docker-machine env testdriven-dev 
$ eval $(docker-machine env testdriven-prod) 
$ export REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=http://18.234.200.115 
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up -d --build
```

`env` was pruned against any dangling images.

Why is this happening?

### Edit

Following advice down on comments, I SSHed into docker-machine to check CPU use during build and, *at the point of hanging*, this is what I get:

```
$ docker-machine ssh testdriven-prod free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1014540      136296      632136       10712      246108      692056
Swap:             0           0           0
```

and:

```
$ docker-machine ssh testdriven-prod df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       16G  2.2G   14G  14% /
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

SSH:

```
top - 01:34:52 up 18 days, 23:47,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 109 total,   1 running, 108 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  1014540 total,   594752 free,   124092 used,   295696 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.   698272 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                            
 8363 root      20   0  435240  21768   3124 S  0.3  2.1  30:07.40 containerd  
    1 root      20   0  185312   4916   2996 S  0.0  0.5   0:12.98 systemd
```

more:

```
ubuntu@testdriven-prod:~$ ps aux -Hww
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:37   [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:17   [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [migration/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:07   [watchdog/0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [kdevtmpfs]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [netns]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [perf]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [xenwatch]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [xenbus]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [khungtaskd]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [writeback]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Feb03   0:00   [ksmd]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Feb03   0:03   [khugepaged]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [crypto]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [kintegrityd]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [kblockd]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [ata_sff]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [md]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [devfreq_wq]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:07   [kswapd0]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [vmstat]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [fsnotify_mark]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [kthrotld]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        58  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        60  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        62  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        63  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        64  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        65  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        66  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        67  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        68  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        69  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        71  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        72  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [scsi_eh_0]
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [scsi_tmf_0]
root        76  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [scsi_eh_1]
root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [scsi_tmf_1]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root        83  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [ipv6_addrconf]
root        96  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [deferwq]
root       258  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [raid5wq]
root       288  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [bioset]
root       310  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:06   [jbd2/xvda1-8]
root       311  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       386  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [iscsi_eh]
root       389  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [ib_addr]
root       392  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [ib_mcast]
root       394  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [ib_nl_sa_wq]
root       397  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [ib_cm]
root       398  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [iw_cm_wq]
root       399  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [rdma_cm]
root       411  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb03   0:00   [kauditd]
root       541  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:02   [kworker/0:1H]
root     23959  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [xfsalloc]
root     23960  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb03   0:00   [xfs_mru_cache]
root     12186  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb21   0:00   [kworker/u30:2]
root     12198  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    00:21   0:00   [kworker/u30:1]
root     12219  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    00:21   0:00   [kworker/0:0]
root     13607  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    02:16   0:00   [kworker/0:2]
root         1  0.0  0.4 185312  5020 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:13 /lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 27
root       366  0.0  0.2  28352  2212 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:04   /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       437  0.0  0.0 102968   372 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:00   /sbin/lvmetad -f
root       942  0.0  0.2  16116  2780 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:00   /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.eth0.leases eth0
root      1091  0.0  0.2  26068  2048 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:01   /usr/sbin/cron -f
daemon    1097  0.0  0.1  26044  1664 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:00   /usr/sbin/atd -f
message+  1101  0.0  0.1  42992  1704 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:01   /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
root      1110  0.0  0.3 272944  3360 ?        Ssl  Feb03   0:20   /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
root      1113  0.0  0.6 636464  7008 ?        Ssl  Feb03   0:07   /usr/bin/lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs/
root      1139  0.0  0.2  28616  2452 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:01   /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
syslog    1140  0.0  0.2 260628  2228 ?        Ssl  Feb03   0:01   /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root      1151  0.0  0.1   4396  1312 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:00   /usr/sbin/acpid
root      1157  0.0  0.0   5220   116 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:38   /sbin/iscsid
root      1158  0.0  0.3   5720  3508 ?        S<Ls Feb03   3:04   /sbin/iscsid
root      1172  0.0  0.0  13372   144 ?        Ss   Feb03   0:00   /sbin/mdadm --monitor --pid-file /run/mdadm/monitor.pid --daemonise --scan --syslog
root      1263  0.0  0.1  12840  1588 ttyS0    Ss+  Feb03   0:00   /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200 38400 9600 ttyS0 vt220
root      1266  0.0  0.1  14656  1472 tty1     Ss+  Feb03   0:00   /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
root      8363  0.1  2.1 435240 21768 ?        Ssl  Feb03  30:09   /usr/bin/containerd
root      9248  0.0  5.6 583988 57744 ?        Ssl  Feb03  18:11   /usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver overlay2 --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label provider=amazonec2
root     24091  0.0  0.1 277088  1652 ?        Ssl  Feb03   0:00   /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root      1068  0.0  0.2  65512  2616 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00   /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root     13498  0.0  0.6  92800  6580 ?        Ss   01:32   0:00     sshd: ubuntu [priv]
ubuntu   13560  0.0  0.3  92800  3352 ?        S    01:32   0:01       sshd: ubuntu@pts/0
ubuntu   13561  0.0  0.5  21388  5104 pts/0    Ss   01:32   0:00         -bash
ubuntu   13617  0.0  0.3  36228  3332 pts/0    R+   02:23   0:00           ps aux -Hww
root     31239  0.0  1.5 292584 15836 ?        Ssl  Feb13   0:20   /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
systemd+ 22714  0.0  0.1 100324  1816 ?        Ssl  Feb20   0:00   /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
root     23340  0.0  0.2  42124  2484 ?        Ss   Feb20   0:00   /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
ubuntu   13500  0.0  0.4  45148  4608 ?        Ss   01:32   0:00   /lib/systemd/systemd --user
ubuntu   13505  0.0  0.2 208764  2032 ?        S    01:32   0:00     (sd-pam)
```

Comment: Those libraries are pretty big and have lots of dependencies. Are you sure it's hung and not just compiling? Is there a process taking up a lot of I/O or CPU when it's hung?

Comment: I've waited for more than 12 hours....and during development, yes it took a while to build it, but not nearly as much. do you know how I can measure CPU while it is trying to build it?

Comment: Use `ps`, `top`, `iotop`, or any other standard tool. If it's running in a Docker Machine use `docker-machine ssh MY_MACHINE_NAME` first.

Comment: @kichik please refer to my edit.

Comment: You posted memory usage and disk space usage but no CPU. Try `top`.

Comment: but in order to use `top` we must have a running container, no?

Comment: No, you're listing all the processes running on the machine where Docker is installed including the build processes.

Comment: @kichik plese refer to edit again. this is the system snapshot while the install is 'hanging'.

Comment: I don't think that's the Docker machine. Why would Chrome be running there? Did you SSH first?

Comment: true. ssh'ed and did `top`. does it make sense now?

Comment: It shows nothing running. Try `ps aux -Hww`. If it still doesn't show anything, maybe there is an actual bug here. Either I am misleading you on where the build is running or the build finished and your local `docker.exe` doesn't see it.

Comment: It's worth noting that having separate Dockerfiles for dev and prod rather defeat the purpose of using Docker. It is better to have one Dockerfile for prod and then add a multi-stage build, so your dev environment inherits from prod (but adds more tools). Even then, it is worth being careful, as diverging these environments can result in production surprises. Always use the production image in test and CI.